# Reading string value appears as NULL

Tags: c, struct, printf, c-strings, strcpy

This program when it receives the input `1`, it receives info from the user and if the input `2` is given it shows what it has stored so far.

The issue is that when you select `2` after having inserted the required info, the name that was provided appears as NULL.

Comment: No `&`: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", OE1);` -- `OE1` is an array; it gets automatically converted to a pointer (to its first element) when used as argument in `scanf()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &OE1);
                  ^^^
```

you need to write

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", OE1);
```

This statement

```
ptr -> OE[NAME_LEN]=OE1[NAME_LEN];
```

does not make a sense.

You need to write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( ptr -> OE, OE1 );
```

This functionality of this if statement

```
   if(head==NULL)
     ptr->next=NULL;
   else
     ptr->next=head;
```

can be performed just by one statement

```
ptr->next = head;
```

And this statement

```
printf("%d     %s    %d\n",ptr->AM, ptr->OE[NAME_LEN], ptr->XS);
```

must be substituted for this one

```
printf("%d     %s    %d\n",ptr->AM, ptr->OE, ptr->XS);
```

Comment: @user17850871 I am sorry I have not understood what you mean.